# CSS counter-increment is not working for nested div and h3 elements

Tags: html, css

I can not make my CSS counters work. They do work somehow, but on nesting level decrement they are off.

Here is my test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chapter Numbering</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    div {
      counter-reset: myitemcounter;
    }
    h3::before {
      counter-increment: myitemcounter;
      content: counters(myitemcounter, ".") " ";
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <h3>This should be ... 1 </h3>
    <h3>This should be ... 2 </h3>
    <div>
      <h3>This should be ... 2.1 </h3>
      <h3>This should be ... 2.2 </h3>
      <h3>This should be ... 2.3 </h3>
      <div>
        <h3>This should be ... 2.3.1 </h3>
        <h3>This should be ... 2.3.2 </h3>
      </div>
      <h3>This should be ... 2.4 </h3>
      <div>
        <h3>This should be ... 2.4.1 </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3>This should be ... 3 </h3>
    <div>
      <h3>This should be ... 3.1 </h3>
      <h3>This should be ... 3.2 </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The expected numbers are in the text of the heading items.
Actual output is (wrong after 2.3.2):

```
1     This should be ... 1
2     This should be ... 2
2.1   This should be ... 2.1
2.2   This should be ... 2.2
2.3   This should be ... 2.3
2.3.1 This should be ... 2.3.1
2.3.2 This should be ... 2.3.2
2.3.3 This should be ... 2.4
2.3.1 This should be ... 2.4.1
2.4   This should be ... 3
2.1   This should be ... 3.1
2.2   This should be ... 3.2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Uh, how about ordered lists or unordered lists?  You can get the same functionality with less problems.

Comment: If you nest them like you would `ul` or `ol` elements (i.e. the divs are nested within the h3s) then it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/9eabn3L3/3/  However this has the side effect of making the font get larger and larger the deeper the nesting goes.

Comment: @JamesMontagne nice fiddle. One could fix it with fixed font-size. However, this is invalid markup, since headings allow only phrasing content and not flow content (which both, div and headings are).

Comment: @Christoph yeah, I wouldn't actually suggest doing this, but all examples I found use lists or a similar nesting structure.  I haven't gotten a chance to read the spec on this to see why and if there's some way to deal with this without that nesting structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters):

> The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter and includes the element's descendants and its following siblings with their descendants.

The important point is that the scope of the counter created by reset is the siblings **and following siblings**.  As a result, when you reset on `div`, this also applies to any following `h3` elements.

You can get this to work the way you expect by instead resetting the counter on the first child of a div:

```
div > :first-child {
    counter-reset: myitemcounter;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9eabn3L3/6

```css
div > :first-child {
    counter-reset: myitemcounter;
}
h3::before {
    counter-increment: myitemcounter;
    content: counters(myitemcounter, ".")" ";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>This should be ... 1 </h3>
    <h3>This should be ... 2 </h3>
    <div>
        <h3>This should be ... 2.1 </h3>
        <h3>This should be ... 2.2 </h3>
        <h3>This should be ... 2.3 </h3>
        <div>
            <h3>This should be ... 2.3.1 </h3>
            <h3>This should be ... 2.3.2 </h3>
        </div>
        <h3>This should be ... 2.4 </h3>
        <div>
            <h3>This should be ... 2.4.1 </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>This should be ... 3 </h3>
    <div>
        <h3>This should be ... 3.1 </h3>
        <h3>This should be ... 3.2 </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can the counters be used only on the `content`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Currently I believe so.

Comment: I imagined so (I didn't get any test to work, and all the examples online are with content). It's a pity, because I think it would make CSS better.

Comment: Amazing! But why does this work with UL elements then? The structure seems to be exactly the same!

Comment: Ah, OK, I see, structure is different, the LI element covers the whole section, H3 does not do that.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Just read the spec, once again...