# CSS counters don't work inside other elements

Tags: css, css-counter

This problem is not a duplicated of [CSS counter-increment is not working for nested div and h3 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524296/css-counter-increment-is-not-working-for-nested-div-and-h3-elements)

I have a problem using CSS counters when the element on which is applied is inside other elements:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>HTML/CSS Tutorials</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>HTML</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>CSS</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Bootstrap</h2>
    </div>
</div>


<h1>Scripting Tutorials</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>jQuery</h2>
<h2>React</h2>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

For the second section it's working fine, but for the first one, the subsection keeps reseting and it's always showing 1. Please advise, thanks!

[image]

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for your reply, but my problem is a little different. I don't have a rule for reset applied to an element which is present on multiple levels, like is the `h3` in the example you provided.

Comment: `counter-reset: subsection;` is applied for element that has no siblings or child elements for first `<h1>`, that's why it's working only in second set of elements

Comment: So there is no fix for my problem?

Comment: You should re-structure your HTML or set `counter-reset` on some wrapper of these elements

Comment: Take a look at this answer. They nest the headings in divs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769190/css-counter-numbered-headings-in-different-div

Comment: @Lisa Thanks, but I cannot change the HTML. I will try to find another solution for this.

Comment: Can you add classes to the divs?

Comment: Posted an answer if you can add a class to h1 parent div.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a class to the h1 parent div, you can do it this way:

```css
h1::before, h2::before {
    color: red;
}
div.heading {
    counter-increment: item;
    counter-reset: item2;
}
div.heading + div {
    counter-increment: item2;
}

div ~ div {
    counter-increment: item2;
}

h1::before {
    content: "Section " counter(item) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    content: counter(item) "." counter(item2) " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
    <div>
        <h1>HTML/CSS Tutorials</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>HTML</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>CSS</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Bootstrap</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="heading">
    <div>
        <h1>HTML/CSS Tutorials</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>HTML</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>CSS</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Bootstrap</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```